# Want to have multiple rows .net table

Tags: c#, .net, html-table

I am wondering why .Net Table rows are being added to the same line instead of multiple lines?

Specifically the problem is with this code:

```
this.table.Rows.AddAt(0,labels);
this.table.Rows.AddAt(1,fields);
this.table.Rows.AddAt(2,submits);
```

table is a WebControls.Table
labels, fields and submits are TableRows
which all include TableCells.

But when I look at it in the browser it is represented like < tr > "all the rows and columns"

< /tr >

and then two empty

< tr > < /tr > < tr > < /tr >

tags..?

So it adds all the content of the cells and the rows and it even adds three rows but for some reason it puts all the info in the first

< tr > 
tag.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

```
<table border="0">
        <tr>
            <td><span>please enter the title of the interaction here</span></td><td><span>please enter the description of the interaction here</span></td><td><span>please select the impact level of the interaction here</span></td><td><span>please select the urgency level of the interaction here</span></td><td><span>please enter the contact of the interaction here</span></td><td><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl06" type="text" value="one" /></td><td><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl07" type="text" value="two" /></td><td><select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl08">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Low</option>
                <option value="2">Medium</option>
                <option value="3">High</option>

            </select></td><td><select name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl09">
                <option selected="selected" value="1">Low</option>
                <option value="2">Medium</option>
                <option value="3">High</option>

            </select></td><td><input name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl10" type="text" value="con" /></td><td rowspan="3"><input type="submit" name="ctl00$PlaceHolderMain$ctl00$ctl11" value="Create Interaction" /></td><td rowspan="2"><span>No interactions created yet</span></td>
        </tr><tr>

        </tr><tr>

        </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: can you show some of the resulting html?

Comment: Ok, thanks. I'm not gonna add this as an answer as I'm not sure if it's correct, but if I had to guess, I'd say that the `AddAt` function doesn't actually `add` rows to the table, just adds data to existing rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can  try with this code, by passing cell container

```
/adding first row
TableRow row1 = new TableRow();

//adding first cell
TableCell cell1 = new TableCell();

//adding label
Label text1 = new Label();
text1.Text = "Just test";

cell1.Controls.Add(text1);
row1.Controls.Add(cell1);
table1.Controls.Add(row1);
```